# If Call js file as async function undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

in my project I need to call javascript file as asynchronous. Ιf i use asynchronous, means script will send a request to the server, and continue it's execution without waiting for the reply. My problem is if I call **JavaScript** file as async "`Uncaught ReferenceError: initcall is not defined` " I face the above error,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "somepath/test.js" async></script>
```

I call initcall() function in html file and I just put `alert()` box in that function, If I run html file means I face this type of error, If I remove async call and run means alert is shown , what is the issue in async call?,I need to make my JavaScript file as async call. Anyone suggest me for my problem

Comment: JS file is loaded asynchronously. You call function before it is loaded and executed, it obviously does not work. If you remove `async`, then browser waits for this JS to load and execute synchronously and it obviously does work if you call `initcall()` after loading `test.js`.

Comment: @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev - obviously I call the function after loading of js then also I face the function undefined error

Comment: You call the function not after loading of js but after telling browser to start loading JS :) By the time you call your function, you cannot know whether it has executed `test.js` or not.

Comment: OK, Is there any other way is there for my problem ?